# Save image's path in sqlite database Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Im totally new in Android programming and I have huge problem with save images and retrieve them from sqlite database. I was searching a lot and I found that the better option is to save only image's path in database. And nhere is my problem. I open gallery and choose picture. And I dont know how to save the picture path in database and then display it in imageview. Should I save the chosen image in application memory or file(or sth like that) and then obtain path rom that or directly path from photo from gallery? Please, help me ! I will be thankful ! A lot !

Comment: you can follow these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539130/what-is-the-best-practice-store-images-in-android-in-sd-card-or-in-sql-lite-db , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729236/whats-the-best-way-to-store-images-in-android

Answer (score 0):

1.Save your absolute path into database,

2.Read your absolute path from database,

3.Display your image by using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) with your path which read from database.